# Can we add membership table to use in c# windows form application

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Firstly I want to confirm that Can I use membership table in c# windows form app? Because when I'm using it, it gives me error on the following line

```
  MembershipCreateStatus mcs = new MembershipCreateStatus();
  MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(txtusername.Text, false);
        if (user != null)
        {
            Msg.Text = "The user name " + Server.HtmlEncode(txtusername.Text) + " already exist. Please Choose another";
            return;
        }
  MembershipUser users = Membership.CreateUser(txtusername.Text, txtpassword.Text, txtusername.Text, "Who am i?", "Patient", true, out mcs);
```

it says "the name server does not exist in the current context". Secondly when I'm omitting this part and writing the following code

```
Msg.Text = "The user name " + txtusername.Text + " already exist. Please Choose another";
```

then after debugging it says following
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can't use Membership class from System.Web in your Windows Forms Application. The reason is that Membership is strongly related with ASP.NET pipeline and intended to use in Web applications. Look at another techniques to secure your app. For example, look at [PrincipalPermissionAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.principalpermissionattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I was having this doubt too. Thank you so much for clarification